# rails find_by_looking_in_every_field ...or... "why is my function missing?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

This is a two parter. I'd be happy with either of the approaches below or other suggestions.

I'd like to be able to retrieve records/objects using my model by passing it a search term and having it look for that search term in *any* field in the model, or any field that the model deems viable. So, as an example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  def search_all_fields(search_term)
    return search_term.length == 0 ? nil : Product.where("serial_number like :find_me", { :find_me => search_term })
  end
end
```

This is from a Product model. The same function in the Company model might look like:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  def search_all_fields(search_term)
    return search_term.length == 0 ? nil : Company.where("customer_number like :find_me or name like :find_me", { :find_me => search_term })
  end
end
```

I would love a "railsy" way to do this, such as "find_by_looking_everywhere" but I haven't been able to find such a thing. I've found lots of suggestions for searching a single field for multiple values, but not searching multiple fields for a single value. So that's "Part 1," is there a "railsy" way to do this?

"Part 2" ... using the code above, why am I getting the following exception?

```
undefined method `search_all_fields` for #<Class:0xa38f2ac>
```

I'm calling the methods using `@products = Product.search_all_fields("xy3445")` or `@companies = Company.search_all_fields("high")`?? The trace shows that the exception is being raised by just a generic class. It doesn't say `#<Product...>` or `#<Company...>`

I'm a little lost... any and all help appreciated.

Thanks, gang.

Comment: You have to make this method as a class method (now you set it has instance method), just simply define it like this: `def self.search_all_fields(search_term)` and then you can call `Company.search_all_fields('bonjour')`

Comment: Thank you, @MrYoshiji. That fixed it. Just to clarify my own understanding: `def self.my_handy_function()` is accessible via `something = MyClass.my_handy_function()` but `def my_handy_function()` is only available within a given instance. Is `def self.something()` similar to defining a static method?

Comment: I posted an answer, take a look ;) @Jamie

Comment: Yup. I've got the distinction now. I still stumble with Ruby. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is an instance method (the Model need to be instanciated to access this method). You need a Class method (means you don't need an instance of Company to call it, like the methods `where()`, `find()` etc).

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  def say_hello
    return "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

This method say_hello can only be **called from an instance** of Company (**instance method**):

```
company = Company.first
company.say_hello #=> "Hello world!"
# but this will raise a NoMethodError:
Company.say_hello #=> NoMethodError
```

In order to **define** a method as a **class method**, you can do the following:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.say_hello
    return "Hello world!"
  end

  # OR you can use the name of the model instead of the self keyword:
  def Company.say_hello
    return "HEllo World!"
  end
end
```

Now you can do:

```
Company.say_hello
#=> "HEllo World!"
# but this will fail:
Company.first.say_hello
#=> NoMethodError
```